# Exclude YouTube from VPN

Tags: openvpn

I am using vpn client (OpenVPN) on my Asus (ASUSWRT) router directly - everything is working like a charm and trafic on all devices in my network are routed via vpn provider.

However I want to exclude all Google trafic (Gmail, Drive) and more specifically YouTube trafic from vpn.

Any suggestions to achieve this by modifying .ovpn file will be highly appriciated - do also let me know if any other solution beside modifying .opvn exist..

Reason 
1) my isp provider offer me a very high speed to Google (Microsoft and few others) products due to co-location and only normal speed for rest of the internet !! 
2) don't want use vpn for YouTube videos as it's wastage of bandwidth via additional Loop.

Thank you in advance for all your help.

Nitin

Answer (score 1):

You **cannot** do this via the VPN configuration files (which have nothing to do with this), but you can do this via a configuration of the routing table.

On the machine which hosts the OpenVPN, client, setup a *second* routing table (you find excellent instructions for this [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/22794/49626)). This second routing table is the routing table your pc would have **without** the OpenVPN running, you just need to copy that.

Now add the following rules:

```
ip rule add to 8.8.8.8/32 table table2 
ip rule add to 8.8.4.4/32 table table2
ip rule add ....
```

for all sites which you want to go **outside** the OpenVPN, then add the following rule:

```
ip rule add from 192.168.1.100 dev eth0 table table2
```

where I assumed your outward-facing interface is called *eth0* and it has IP address *192.168.1.100*, if not change accordingly.

Comment: Thanks MariusMatutiae, I will try this today on my laptop, should work as you describe, many thanks. However this solve half of my problem as I do have smart TV and android etc devices I use for YouTube etc. Thanks again as I now have a temporary way for my laptop.